# Getting same X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK error each time trying to install openai package

Tags: x509certificate, x509, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Each time I try to "pip install openai" I receive the below error message. I have tried installing various versions of cryptography, uninstalling and reinstalling using homebrew, still not working. Any ideas on steps I can follow to successfully install openai for the chatgpt API? I'm using a Mac OS for context.

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1537, in X509StoreFlags
CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Thank you

Steps Followed trying to debug:
Mentioned above -- installing and uninstalling versions of crpytography using homebrew and terminal...